# Random string from string array list

Tags: java, android

I have list of countries in my array, I would like to pick random country from the list (using random probably?), but I haven't found out the answer myself...

This is what I have so far:

```
String[] list = {"Finland", "Russia", "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Poland"};
Random r = new Random();
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try:

```
list[r.nextInt(list.length)];
```

Comment: @roni: Burleigh Bear is correct, the value will never be list.length. As per the Java documentation: "Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value **(exclusive)**"

Comment: @Burleigh Bear Can you please tell me how can I choose a random string from that array and also I want some other string every time. I mean if I don't want to repeat the string value what's modification I need in this code .

Comment: The usual way to do that is to permute the list (i.e. do a shuffle - you can look up Knuth's algorithm for this). Then you can just iterate through the list to return each item successively.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answers is not working for me the solution worked for me is

```
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");
```

Suppose you have this above `ArrayList` and you want to randomize it

```
    Random r = new Random();

    int randomitem = r.nextInt(myList.size());
    String randomElement = myList.get(randomitem);
```

If you print this `randomElement` variable you will get random string from your `ArrayList`

Answer (score 2):

```
static String getRandomString(){
        int r = (int) (Math.random()*5);
        String name = new String [] {"India","USA","UK","Russia"}[r];
        return name;
    }
```

Comment: If you have 4 strings in the array, you should use 
        ```int r = (int) (Math.random()*4);```

Answer (score 1):

Ran into a similar problem with pulling a random string from a string array.
Found this to work fairly well, I applied it to a button action so with every click a random is drawn(I found with any array size there are multiple instances of the same string being drawn consecutively throughout):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random.*;

class Countries {
    public Random g2 = new Random();
    public String[] list = new String[] { "Finland", "Russia",
            "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Poland" };
    String random2;
}

// Applied to a button action:
int INDEXn = g2.nextInt(list.length);
for (int i2 = 0; i2 < INDEXn; i2++) {
    random2 = (String) (list[INDEXn]);
}
System.out.println(random2 + '\n');
```

The `g2` random that is being used by `INDEXn` is calling a random integer, in this case the defined strings are turned into integer values, from the String array `list`.
The for-loop is cycling through the String array one time.
The random2 string is converting the chosen integer from `INDEXn` to the appropriate string variable in (`list[INDEXn]`).

Answer (score 0):

```
list[Math.floor(r.nextFloat()*5.99)]
```

Comment: because of the floor. you will not get a uniform distribution as 5 will only be the result when getFloat returns 1.0.

Comment: But there is only 5 entries so you want a uniform distribution for 0..4 not 5.

Comment: Why floor a float rather than just using an integer?

Comment: 4.99 will means there is slightly less chance of getting 4 as the rest, why not 5?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void pickText(){ 
    textview textView1= (TextView) findViewById(R.Id.textView1)
    Random eventPicker = new Randorn();
    randomN = eventPicker.nextInt(3) +1; 

    switch (randomN){ 
        case 1: Intent a textview1.setText(StringOne);
        break; 

        case 2: textview1.setText(StringTwo);
        break;
```

I typed it from my phone there's prob syntax errors but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution in 1 line:

`String country = new String[] {"Finland", "Russia", "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Poland"}[(int)(Math.random()*5)];`

Answer (score -1):

import java.util.Random;
public static void main (String [] args){

// For this code, we are trying to pic a random day from days

```
String [] days = {"Sunday","Monday",
            "Tuesday",
            "Wednesday",
            "Thursday",
            "Friday",
            "Saturday"};

Random rand = new Random();

int Rand_item = rand.nextInt(days.length);

System.out.println(days[Rand_item]);
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).