# Android java how to have it select a random string from a predetermined list of strings

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Random string from string array list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726963/random-string-from-string-array-list)

How can I make it where i can press a button and it display one sting (words) at random from a long list of of other strings that i have already set.

Comment: Ehem... do you want to know how to implement a button, how to display a string, or how to choose a random string from a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(...);
list.add(...);
list.add(...);
Random rand = new Random();
String random = list.get(rand.nextInt(list.size()));
```

or:

```
Collections.shuffle(list);
String random = list.get(0);
```